# How to plot an implicit solution of a differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

The question is to find and sketch the solution of the following initial value problem: 
$$(x-y)dx+(3x+y)dy=0$$ and for $x=3$ we have $y=-2$.

I was able to  find an implicit solution using

```
DSolve[{(x - y[x]) + (3x + y[x]) y'[x] == 0, y[3] == -2}, y[x], x]
```

> ```
> Solve[Log[1 + y[x]/x] - 2/(1 + y[x]/x) == -6 - Log[x], y[x]]
> ```

Is it possible to plot the implicit solution? I tried using the general solution -

```
sol = DSolve[(x - y[x]) + (3*x + y[x])*y'[x] == 0, y[x], x]
expr = C[1] /. Solve[sol[[1]], C[1]][[1]] /. {y[x] -> y}
```

and then

```
ContourPlot[expr, {x, 0, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

However, I want to plot

```
Solve[Log[1 + y[x]/x] - 2/(1 + y[x]/x) == -6 - Log[x], y[x]]
```

Comment: `ContourPlot[
 Log[1 + y/x] - 2/(1 + y/x) + 6 + Log[x] == 0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -2, 1}]` ?

Answer (score 9):

The main issue we encounter here is that equation solvig functionality doesn't work quite seamlessly for various types of transcendental functions.  However looking at the result of `DSolve` it appears convenient to introduce a new variable $z=\log(1+\frac{y(x)}{x})$.

```
z[x] == Log[1+ y[x]/x]
```

Now we can find the exact solution, setting up the initial condition in terms of `z[x]`, i.e. `z[3] == -Log[3]`:

```
z[x]/.First @ DSolve[{0==(x - y[x]) + (3x + y[x])y'[x]/.{
                                         y[x] -> x (Exp[z[x]] - 1),
                                         y'[x] -> D[x(Exp[z[x]] - 1), x]}//Simplify,
                       z[3] == -Log[3]},
                       z[x], x] // Quiet
```

> ```
> -6 - Log[x] + ProductLog[2 E^6 x]
> ```

that is `Log[1+ y[x]/x] ==  -6 - Log[x] + ProductLog[2 E^6 x]` i.e. the solution of our equation is `y[x] == f[x]` such, that

```
f[x_] := E^(-6 + ProductLog[2 E^6 x]) - x
```

because

```
FullSimplify[x (Exp[-6 - Log[x] + ProductLog[2 E^6 x]] - 1), x > 0]

% // TraditionalForm
```

> ```
>  E^(-6 + ProductLog[2 E^6 x]) - x
> ```

[image]

where `W` is the Lambert function.  Now we can plot the graph of the solution. However since it looks like a straight line, we find an example of a linear  function to compare the both graphs. We assume that the graphs intersect at `x  == 0` and `x == 3` and so:

```
g[x_] = a x + b /. First @ Solve[{ f[0] == b, f[3] == 3 a + b}, {a, b}]
```

> ```
>  1/E^6 - ((1 + 2 E^6) x)/(3 E^6)
> ```

```
Plot[{ f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed}, 
                    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{3, -2}]}]
```

[image]

The graph is very close to a linear function as could be seen from `ContourPlot`. It might be convenient to plot the difference of the both functions:

```
Plot[ Re @ f[x] - g[x], {x, -3, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Magenta}, 
                                    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{3, 0}]}]
```

[image]

For completeness we plot the real and imaginary values of `f[x]` since it becomes complex for negative numbers (this is independendent from the physical (?) model discribed by the original equation)

```
Plot[ Flatten @ {ReIm @ f[x], g[x]}, {x, -20, 20}, 
        PlotStyle -> {Thick, Thick, Dashed}, Evaluated -> True, 
        Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[{3, -2}]}]
```

[image]