# Verification of a general solution to d'Alembert equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I solved a nonlinear differential equation (d'Alembert one) by hand. *Mathematica* gives the same answer.

But I am not able to get *Mathematica* to verify the solution due to branch cuts.

Any one knows of a trick to verify the solution?

I tried different assumptions but can't find the right set. I know the solution is correct, well, at least I get same solution, but wanted to see if there is a trick to verify the solution back into the ODE, that is all.

```
 ClearAll[y,x];
 ode = y'[x] == Sqrt[1 + x + y[x]]
 sol = DSolve[ode, y, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image]

Tried

```
  Simplify[ode /. sol]
  Assuming[Element[x, Reals] && x > 0, FullSimplify[ode /. sol]]
```

and so on. Not able to get `True`.

### Appendix

hand solution

Solve
\begin{align*}
      {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) &=\sqrt {1+x+y \left( x \right) }
\end{align*}

This is d'Alembert ODE. It has the form
$y \left( x \right) =x g(y'(x)) + f(y'(x))$. where
$g$ and $f$ are functions of  $y'(x)$.

Solving for $y \left( x \right) $ from the above and keeping only real solutions
for $y \left( x \right) $ and letting $p=y'(x)$ gives
\begin{align*}
y \left( x \right)  &= {p}^{2}-x-1 \tag{1} \\ 
\end{align*}
ODE (1) is now solved.

In this ODE $g(y'(x)) = -1$ and $f(y'(x))={p}^{2}-1$.
Taking derivatives of (1) w.r.t. $x$ and remembering that $p$ is a function of $x$ results in
\begin{align*}
          p &= -1+ \left(2\,p\right) \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}}\\ 
          p+1 &= \left(2\,p\right) \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}}\tag{2}\\ 
\end{align*}
The singular solution is found by setting $ \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}}=0$, which implies that $p$ is a constant. From the above, this results in
\begin{align*}
        p+1&=0\\ 
\end{align*}
Solving the above for $p$ gives
\begin{align*}
p&=-1\\ 
\end{align*}

Substituting $-1$ values in (1) gives the singular solution
$$
y \left( x \right) =-x
$$
But this solution does not satisfy the ODE, hence will not be used

The general solution is  found when $ \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}}\neq 0$. Rewriting (2) as
\begin{align*}
    \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}} &={\frac {p+1}{2\,p}}\\ 
\end{align*}
Inverting the above gives
\begin{align*}
       \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}p}} &=2\,{\frac {p}{p+1}}
\end{align*}
$x \left( p \right) $ is now the dependent variable and $p$ as the independent variable.
Now this ODE is solved for $x \left( p \right) $.
Since ${\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}p}}x \left( p \right)  = 2\,{\frac {p}{p+1}}$ then
$$
x \left( p \right)  = \int{2\,{\frac {p}{p+1}} \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}} = 2\,p-2\,\ln  \left( p+1 \right)  + C
$$
Solving (using the computer) for $p$ from the above in terms of $x$ gives
\begin{align*}
 p &= - \mathrm{LambertW} \left( -{{\rm e}^{-{\frac {x}{2}}-1+{\frac {C_{{1}}}{2}}}} \right) -1\\ 
\end{align*}
Substituting the above solution for $p$ in Eq (1) gives the general solution.

$$
y \left( x \right) = \left( \mathrm{LambertW} \left( -{{\rm e}^{-{\frac {x}{2}}-1+{\frac {C_{{1}}}{2}}}} \right)  \right) ^{2}+2\, \mathrm {LambertW} \left( -{{\rm e}^{-x/2-1+1/2\,C_{{1}}}} \right) -x
$$

ps. `LambertW` is `ProductLog`

Comment: As an aside, you can substitute `y[x] == v[x] - x` which turns the ODE into a separable equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues to be clarified: **appropriate form** of our **differential equation** and **appropriate domain of the solution**. Both issues are not independent and they arise due to playing with a general form of `DSolve` without specification of apropriate initial conditions.
In order to demonstrate that the equation is satisfied we define:

```
ode = y'[x]^2 == 1 + x + y[x]
sol = DSolveValue[ode, y, x] // Quiet
```

We have chosen this way of defining `ode` in order to avoid checking whether `y'[x] == Sqrt[1 + x + y[x]]` or `y'[x] == -Sqrt[1 + x + y[x]]`. (it is a simple exercise to observe that this issue comes out when an integration constant is specified).
The solution depends on its variable `x` and its parameter `c` (which could be determined   with the initial conditions given).

```
f[x_, c_] := -x + 2 ProductLog[-E^(-1 - x/2 - c/2)] + ProductLog[-E^(-1 - x/2 - c/2)]^2
f[x,c] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

and now with appropriate domain of definiton (`x > -c` we assume that the solution is real like the original question seemed to assume, although this point in unnecessary) we have

```
Simplify[ ode /. {y[x] -> f[x, c], y'[x] -> Derivative[1, 0][f][x, c]}, x > -c]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

When we deal with special functions like the Lambert W function (`ProductLog`) we should use `FullSimplify` rather than `Simplify`, nonetheless we chose the latter to show that it is straightforward checking whether this differential equation is satisfied.
**QED**

**Example c=1**

```
With[{c = 1}, 
  Plot[ ReIm @ f[x, c], {x, -3/2, 1/2}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.008], 
        AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Evaluated -> True]]
```

[image]

We can see that the solution is real for $x\geq-c=-1$ and its derivative is negative as mentioned above.

For quite a similar problem consider examining [How to plot an implicit solution of a differential equation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215360/how-to-plot-an-implicit-solution-of-a-differential-equation/215370#215370) where we had to change the variables in order to go ahead with reasonable analysis.